# Swap n per page and page numbers at the bottom of the Question lists

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, questions, user-interface, design

It is probably too late now to change it, but I'd prefer the

```
prev [1] [2] [3] ... next
```

pages on the left at the bottom and the

```
[15] [30] [50] per page
```

on the right at the bottom of question lists.

Comment: Pretty sure it was prev/next on the left before.

Comment: We should put the *prev next* in the middle at the bottom and the *per page* in the middle at the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was actually a bit of a mistake in some refactoring, and I will fix it with the next deployment.

It's easy now though...

```
<div class="page-sizer fl">
<div class="pager fr">
```

Guess what `fr` and `fl` stand for?

Comment: France and Florida?

Comment: So [bug] would have been a more correct tag? :-)